# Need the array at index zero in some different manner

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$i=0;
foreach($tagss as $tagdetails)
    {
        if($i==0)
 $tags_array[]["00"]=array("id"=>$i,"name"=>"all","type"=>"gift_finder","parent_id"=>null,"url"=>"all","readonly"=>"0","deleted"=>"0");


 $tags_array[][$tagdetails->id]=array("id"=>$tagdetails->id,"name"=>$tagdetails->title,"type"=>"gift_finder","parent_id"=>null,"url"=>$tagdetails->title,"readonly"=>"0","deleted"=>"0");


    $i++;
    }
echo json_encode($tags_array);
```

my out put of above code is :-

```
[{"00":{"id":0,"name":"all","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"all","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}},{"1":{"id":"1","name":"Adventure","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"Adventure","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}},{"2":{"id":"2","name":"cool","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"cool","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}}]
```

that is the right but i want the out put like (just need 0 instead of 00)
so i tried :-

```
   $i=0;
foreach($tagss as $tagdetails)
    {
        if($i==0)
 $tags_array[]["0"]=array("id"=>$i,"name"=>"all","type"=>"gift_finder","parent_id"=>null,"url"=>"all","readonly"=>"0","deleted"=>"0");


 $tags_array[][$tagdetails->id]=array("id"=>$tagdetails->id,"name"=>$tagdetails->title,"type"=>"gift_finder","parent_id"=>null,"url"=>$tagdetails->title,"readonly"=>"0","deleted"=>"0");


    $i++;
    }
echo json_encode($tags_array);
```

ouput of the above code :-

```
[[{"id":0,"name":"all","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"all","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}],{"1":{"id":"1","name":"Adventure","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"Adventure","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}},{"2":{"id":"2","name":"cool","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"cool","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}}]
```

that is logically right that it is put the first element in the array and treat next element at first index but i need 0 index separately

Any suggestion please 
thanks in advance .

in summary I need

```
[{"0":{"id":0,"name":"all","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"all","readonly":"0",
"deleted":"0"}},
{"1":"id":"1","name":"Adventure","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"Adventure","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}},
{"2":"id":"2","name":"cool","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"cool","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}
}]
```

Comment: why are you using "00" instead of "0"

Comment: might want to try setting $r[""] = ""; that way it is forced to be hashed and not indexed

Comment: i guess there is a wrong syntax in `{"1":"id":"1","name":"Adventure"...`
and in `{"2":"id":"2","name":"cool"...`

Comment: i don't understand your question or you can JSON_FORCE_OBJECT in json_encode or conver int to string, or string to in, if it helps

Comment: thanks but i tried int and string casting but not worked for me. And tried "" as well

Comment: @artmees the syntax is right that's why the json is creating properly but the indexing is not getting right that i want .thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass option to your `json_encode()` call. It is [JSON_FORCE_OBJECT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php):

```
echo json_encode($tags_array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

then you'll able to result in an object for numeric keys (so you don't need to pass keys from PHP at all). Please, note, that is available since PHP 5.3

Comment: thanks it works for changing the indexing but 
it creates like
Logo
{"0":{"0":{"id":0,"name":"all","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"all","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}},"1":{"1":{"id":"1","name":"Adventure","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"Adventure","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}},"2":{"2":{"id":"2","name":"cool","type":"gift_finder","parent_id":null,"url":"cool","readonly":"0","deleted":"0"}}}

Comment: but i want the indexing  dynamically i mean it will changed randomly
just the first index will same i.e zero 0